# SYCL Explicit Data Movement from Image to Host

Tags: c++, opencl, intel-oneapi, sycl

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do explicit data transfer to/from host when using sycl::image.  I'm familiar with sycl::handler.copy when using buffers:

```
float* host_ptr;
sycl::buffer<float, 1> buf;
sycl::queue& q
q.submit([&](sycl::handler& cgh) {
  auto acc = buf.get_access<sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
  cgh.copy(acc, host_ptr);
});

q.wait_and_throw();
```

but I can't quite find the equivalent code when dealing with sycl::image.  If I pass an image accessor to .copy it complains that the accessor doesn't have a subscipt operator.  Does anyone know the correct method for this?

My previous OpenCL code had **clEnqueueReadImage** and **clEnqueueWriteImage** for this sort of data image transfer.  Is there a sycl equivalent?

note: I'm aware of the implicit copy back to host on sycl::image deconstruction, but I want to know the explicit solution, rather than the implicit one.